# Is this sentence correct? courtesy/honorific use of the passive

Tags: grammar, particles, syntax, passive-voice

> 総理大臣【そうりだいじん】はヨーロッパを訪問【ほうもん】されたくさんの国々の大統領【だいとうりょう】に会われた。
>
> "The prime minister visited Europe and met the presidents of various countries".

され is as this to link the phrase right?

Why use "を" as if it were a normal sentence? Wouldn't it be "で" or "に" as a normal passive sentence?

Are Honorific/Courtesy sentences treated as if they were normal sentences even though they are conjugated using the passive form in the verbs?

Comment: The され is not passive but honorific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is perfectly correct. The auxiliary (助動詞) 「れる/られる」 has four meanings: 「受け身」(passive), 「尊敬」(honorific), 「可能」(potential), and 「自発」(spontaneous). Here in your example, it is used as honorific.

> 総理大臣はヨーロッパを訪問**され**たくさんの国々の大統領に**会われ**た。

is not the passive voice, but the honorific speech (尊敬語) of:

> 総理大臣はヨーロッパを訪問**し**たくさんの国々の大統領に**会っ**た。

Which *literally* means:

> The prime minister **visited** Europe and **met** the presidents of various countries.