# What does the phrase 落し物をされる mean in this sentence? It doesn't sound like correct passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

The context is that someone has lost a present and the main character goes to look for it. He goes up to a shopkeeper who asks him what's wrong and he responds with

> ええ、少々探し物を。昨日チャミーさんが**落し物をされたらしくて**。。。何か気づかれませんでしたか？

This looks like the passive form. I'm confused because if Mrs. Chammy is the subject here, then what is being done to her and who is doing it?

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/is-this-sentence-correct-courtesy-honorific-use-of-the-passive

Comment: @JansthcirlU Yeah that's it. Thank you.